# Changing value of several variables due to the actual value in variable

Tags: powershell

I have a lot of values extracted from a file and depending of the value af each variable I what to change the value through a foreach loop. But somethis is not working as I expected...
there is an example:

```
$a="1"  
$B="2"  
$C="3"  
$D=$a, $b, $c  
Foreach ($Element in $C)  
{  
  If ($Element -eq "1")
  {
    $Element ="Red"
  }
  Elseif ($Element -eq "2")
  {
    $Element = "Green"
  }
  Else 
  {
    $Element = "Blue"
  }
}
```

What I expected is that the values in `$a`, `$b`, `$c` was change from `1`, `2`, `3` to `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through elements in `$C`, while the array is actually `$D`, but this change alone will not fix it.

The solution depends on the type of objects you have in the variables a -> c. If they are `int`, `bool` ++, they are value-types which are just copied to `$Element` in the loop. Modifying `$Element` inside the loop will only update the value stored in `$Element`, while `$a` stays untouched.

However, if the variables contains "normal objects" which are reference-types, then `$Element` contains a pointer to the object and modifications to `$Element` will also be reflected in `$a`.

While `string` in your example is actually a reference-type, it behaves like a value-type (`$Element =..` doesn't update `$a`) because it is immutable, which means it doesn't change, but actually creates a new object on every modification.

You could use `Get-Variable` to access the variables by passing in variable-names in the array. This way, it will support both types. Example:

```
#Sample objects
$a=[pscustomobject]@{MyProperty="1"}
$B=[pscustomobject]@{MyProperty="2"}
$C="3"

$AutoUpdateVariables="a","b","c"

#If variables are value-type (ex. int), just remove .MyProperty
Foreach ($element in (Get-Variable -Name $AutoUpdateVariables))
{  
    If ($element.Value.MyProperty -eq "1")
    {
        $element.Value.MyProperty ="Red"
    }
    Elseif ($element.Value.MyProperty -eq "2")
    {
        $element.Value.MyProperty = "Green"
    }
    Elseif (-not $element.Value.MyProperty)
    {
        #If MyProperty doesn't exist/is null, set variable to "Blue"
        $element.Value = "Blue"
    }
}
```

Update: If you just need to transform a value on execution, you could create a function or a hashtable, ex:

```
$a="1"
$B="2"
$C="3"

$HashTable = @{
    "1" = "Red"
    "2" = "Green"
    "3" = "Blue"
}

#As a string value
"Hello '$a' you value should be '$($HashTable[$a])'"
"Hello '$b' you value should be '$($HashTable[$b])'"

#or as a parameter
Get-ChildItem -Path ($HashTable[$c])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$a="1"  
$B="2"  
$C="3"  
$D=$a,$b,$c  
Foreach ($Element in $D)  
{  
If ($Element -eq "1")
{
$a ="Red"
}
Elseif ($Element -eq "2")
{
$b = "Green"
}
Else 
{
$c = "Blue"
}
}
```

There are two things to be noted in your code. First, you are not iterating over `$D` (you are doing it for `$C`). `$c` has only one element and you don't need a `foreach` loop for that. Second, in the `foreach` loop, you are just changing the values of `$element`, but not the values of `$a`, `$b` and `$c`. Fix those errors, and you are good to go.

Comment: Maybe I explained it wrong. The values in $a, $b and $c are changing depending of what I collect from a file. This can be 1,2 or 3, when I run it through the loop. Next time I run the loop the value can be another - But always 1,2 or 3. I want the loop to change this value to Red, Green, Blue depending of the value at the given time. and after some time I collect new values to $a, $b and $c and run the loop again. $A, $B and $C needs to change value depending of the input value when the loop run.

Comment: Thanx a lot exactly what I needed